# JPanel repaint() or revalidate() not updating JPanel

Tags: java

JPanel `repaint()` or `revalidate()` is not updating my JPanel.

It is working if I don't clear the panel. But I have to update the layout. For an instance, if the table got booked, then I have to change its image (icon).

```
jPanel7.removeAll();//Removing all Components From Japnel If Any. 
//jPanel7.revalidate();
//jPanel7.repaint();
// jPanel7.updateUI();
//        
//}
jPanel7.repaint();      
try{ResultSet result=new DataBase().Read("select * from tables");
    while(result.next()){
        JLabel lbl=new JLabel(); JLabel obj = new   JLabel();
        lbl.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", 4, 24));
        lbl.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);          
        lbl.setText(String.valueOf(result.getString("number")));           
        obj.setName(String.valueOf(result.getString("number")));lbl.setName(String.valueOf(result.getString("number")));    
        lbl.setSize(40, 30); obj.setSize(185, 120);
        obj.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        obj.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 4, 14));
        obj.setBackground(new Color(241,108,93));
        obj.setVisible(true);
        if(count>5)
        {                
            x=7;
            y += 140;
            count=1;                
            obj.setText("<html>Somthing"+"<br> In New Line</html>");
        }else{
            obj.setText(String.valueOf(result.getString("number")));
        }
        jPanel7.add(lbl);  
        jPanel7.add(obj); 

        obj.setLocation(x, y);  
        lbl.setLocation(x+95,y+45);
        if(result.getString("isbooked").equals("YES")){
            Graphics.setLabelIcon(obj, result.getString("type")+"BOOKED.png");
        }else
            Graphics.setLabelIcon(obj, result.getString("type")+".png");
        x+=205;
        count++; 
        lbl.addMouseListener(evt);
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    new PopUp(e.getMessage().toString()).setVisible(true);
}
```

Output--> when I don't clear the JPanel. But when I clear it and try to add components, it doesn't show any output

[image]

Comment: For a better an sooner help please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: are you able to remote my PC.?

Comment: No, did you read the [MCVE]?

Comment: Ok Thanks.  i ll try for this.

Comment: Hello Sir. Thanks, i resolved it. 
as you said  i created it from scratch. Working Fine Now.

Comment: Well Done!! I'm so glad. Most of the time creating a [MCVE] shows us the flaw in our code. And if we couldn't find that flaw ourselves, by posting that minimal code which shows the problem many pro users here in the community will help you with that!

Comment: So Much Thanxs In Favor.